# Brand New Propane Range Not Boiling Water

Tags: range, propane

So I have a new GE JGBS66REK4SS Gas Range, that has been converted to propane. I am currently running it off a BBQ cylinder with a single-stage regulator, until the propane company and plumber permanently installs the lines. And yes, I turn the BBQ cylinder off after every use. I have a 1/2 in OD gas line running from the cylinder to the range that is rated for 62,500 BTUs/hr. No leaks, I checked with soapy water.

I am very confident I performed the conversion correctly, I followed the instructions to the tee. Yeah, I know ... amateur hour :-)

Two things:

- I boogered up the threads on the right rear burner installing the
  orifice, and now I have a new tube on the way from parts dr. I thought about cutting new threads but ... ummmm ... no. I'll pay the $20.
- I happened to raise the lid without first unscrewing the burners. This kinked a
  couple of tubes *VERY* slightly (maybe 1 mm) but they unkinked when I
  lowered it back and then did it right. But the flames look great, nice and blue with no yellow tips. The burners operate over the whole range of the valve. I can't believe I wrecked it here, but I'm willing to acknowledge it if I did.

As far as capabilities:

- The front left burner is rated for 15K BTUs/hr
- The front right is rated for 9.5K BTUs/hr

So the problem is that this thing takes *FOREVER* to boil water. Seriously ... like 30 mins for a 1/2 gallon. And the boil is low quality, little bubbles, and a teensy bit of roll.

Contrast that to a $40 bottle-top camp stove, rated at 10K BTUs/hr. This baby quickly brings the water to a furious rolling boil in ... well, I didn't time it ... but a heck of a lot quicker.

Should this stove be that slow in boiling water?

Comment: Off hand would you have a lack of amount of fuel flow for it to work well, the stove is not getting enough fuel.  Burning the fuel at a low or medium rate instead of a high rate, so water takes longer.

Comment: I don't think this is worthy of an answer, but "no" it should not take half an hour to boil half a gallon of water.  Largest burner on high and lid on pot right?  It should take 5 minutes.  The unstated question is, "What's wrong?".  Start by calling GE using the number in the manual.  You may need a plumber with appropriate test equipment.

Comment: @jay613 lid is not on the pot. But even still, the camp stove outruns it ... lid off, same volume of water. Maybe I shouldn't have DIYed this ...

Comment: Same pot on the camp stove?  On a camp stove you would tend to use pots that are narrower and taller.     If I don't put lids on my pots, boiling water takes a long time.  I have one "Rapid Boil" burner, it's an inferno, and even that would take 10 minutes to boil half a gallon without a lid.  The smaller burners, I expect maybe half an hour or more, IDK.  Maybe your conversion is good and your expectations are wrong.  Did you have this on Natural Gas before, or did you own a gas range previously and did you time it with no lid?  Starting temp of water matters too.  Is your water really cold?

Comment: Deleted orginal answer.  When you stated you follow all the instructions in your conversions, did you do the adjustment to the gas regulator in the stove and change the regulator from NG to LP?

Comment: @Programmer66 yes, there was a cap on the regulator that needed to be flipped, and then change the oven orifice, and adjust the air shutter until oven burner flames were steady blue with intermittent yellow tips, and did not "jet" away from the burner. Then changed out the orifices on the cooktop.

Comment: @jay613 yes, same pot, 9" in diameter. Tried it just now and the campstove brought water to a rapid boil in 6 min flat. I took that pot (still boiling!) over to the largest burner on the stove, and it held it at just a moderate boil. The flame on the stove is 6" diameter, nice pretty blue with no yellow tips. Maybe my expectations are wrong. Not on NG before, water was warm from previous experiment, but not hot.

Comment: That was a good experiment!   Something is wrong.  Not sure what.  Maybe to do with regulators.  Are you using two regulators?  BBQ one external and NG one internal to the stove?   This is wild guessing.  I know you want to blame your conversion work. but it's fairly lego-like and you probably got it right.  There are lots of youtube tutorials on that .. "convert ge range from natural gas to propane".  Watch some.

Comment: @jay613 oh believe me I did ... I am scared to death of fuel gas. That's why I didn't want to go rogue and try to retap those threads. I'll just spend the $22, thank you very much :-) Conducting experiment now ... 1 gal of room-temp water on stove. Currently at 11 min with tiny 1mm bubbles on bottom of pan

Comment: Are you sure you fitted the correct orifices?

Comment: @SolarMike absolutely positive

Comment: OK, so I did a not-so-scientific experiment. 1 Gallon of room-temp water in a 9 in-diameter pot, 8 in high, Depth about 3.5 in, which is about a gallon. Camp stove (10K BTU/hr) boils it in 9:45, range top (15K BTU/hr) boils it in 18 minutes, almost twice as long. Can't see anything wrong with the flame on the range or the setup. The only thing I can figure is that the flame on the camp stove is focused on a smaller central area of the pot, and less heat is wasted around the sideof the pot

Answer (score 1):

Two things --

1. A barbecue tank regulator is typically set for about 1 PSI. Your range requires a pressure of 11-13 inches water column, according to the manual. One PSI is about 28 inches water column, so you're feeding far too much pressure. I've seen regulators that cut flow to a minimum when there's too much gas flow, then reset when flow stops.
2. I know you changed the orifice, but did you also do the natural gas to propane conversion on the range's own regulator? You typically have to remove a cap on the regulator and reverse a pin that sets pressure. See the instructions on the plate at the bottom left rear of the range.

Comment: Yes, I did change the range regulator, there is a threaded brass insert that the instructions called for reversing, as well as moving the plastic cap retaining ring to the other side of the brass insert.